# How does knockout dataFor/contextFor work, exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Background:

When the equivalent of javascript blur happens, I want to be able to edit the selectedOptions bound to a select list through knockout. For instance, select a specific element from a list, or clear the selection.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101763/input-lostfocus-onblur-event-in-knockout) topic which suggests two methods of implementing the "blur" part.

I would prefer to use the solution offered by Chris Pratt, as the system involves a lot of generated code, and it is much simpler if I don't have to change the knockout portion of it. All of my attempts so far have been using Chris Pratt's solution.

In my javascript, I am getting a handle on the relevant DOM elements with no problems. However, I am having difficulties getting a handle on the selectedOptions koobservablearray which is bound to the select. When I call ko.dataFor(DOMobject), it seems to return functions which return regular javascript arrays which are copies of my koobservablearrays, meaning that I can't edit them in order to change which option is selected.

Question:

So, is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do from "outside" of knockout, using methods like ko.dataFor or ko.contextFor? How are these methods intended to work? What are they good for?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say it "seems to return functions which return regular javascript arrays" -- that's what observable arrays are.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: does that mean that I can apply methods on the objects that belong to KoObservableArrays? For instance, is:

`a = ko.dataFor(DOMobj);
a.prop.removeAll;`

Valid?

Comment: I'm saying `dataFor` seems to be returning an observable array in this case. Instead of asking whether something will work, you could just try it.